# ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def main():

    sent_file = open(sys.argv[1])
    tweet_file=open(sys.argv[2])

    scores={}
    for line in sent_file:
       term, score=line.split("/t")
       scores[term]=int(score)
```

the sent_file is something like this:

```
abandon  -2
abandoned   -2
```

each separated by `\t`, could anybody help me figure out this problem?

Comment: You're meant to be using `\t` to represent a tab char... The code you show is using `/t` so you're ending up with a single element list (the original line), which can't be unpacked into two elements...

Comment: Fixing that will fix the problem... You should probably just post an answer, @JonClements

Comment: yes, I used "\t" in the code,"/t" is a typo. @JonClements

Comment: @Dan: Why not edit your post and correct that? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to skip empty lines or lines without a `\t`, just catch the `ValueError` exception in those cases:

```
for line in sent_file:
    try:
        term, score = line.split("\t")
        scores[term] = int(score)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

However, from the comments it appears you have data that is space-separated as well (`'abilities 2\n'` has no `\t` character in the line), so perhaps you should split on general whitespace instead:

```
for line in sent_file:
    try:
        term, score = line.rsplit(None, 1)  # split on last whitespace separator
        scores[term] = int(score)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Now you are splitting on the last arbitrary-width separator on the line (not counting whitespace at the start and end), and only splitting once. If any of your terms contain whitespace too, this ensures that they are preserved. This assumes your score values do not have any whitespace in them (which would also break with your own code).

If you are certain that all you have is `\t` separated data, or you can clean up your input files to use only tabs, an alternative could be to use the `csv` module instead, and to use a dict comprehension:

```
import csv

with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as sent_file:
    reader = csv.reader(sent_file, delimiter='\t')
    scores = {term: int(score) for term, score in reader}
```

Comment: That would solve the error, but it would ignore everything in the file. Here is the link of the file.https://www.dropbox.com/s/u9e931tfzmruj21/AFINN-111.txt

Comment: @Dan: Your comment lost all formatting. Are you saying every line would throw the `ValueError`? What happens if you replace the `pass` with `print repr(line)`?

Comment: The output is: 'abilities    2\n', which means the program stopped at line 11 in the sent_file, I realized the formatting thing, so I created a link of the sent_file.

Comment: @Dan: That means you have values that are *space* separated, not tab separated.

Comment: Maybe, I download an original file, and the problem is fixed now, thank you, Martijn!

Comment: @Dan you may by the looks of it also be interested in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463338/can-i-use-nltk-to-determine-if-a-comment-is-a-positive-one-or-a-negative-one